# Name of interrogation technique used on multiple suspects

Tags: interrogation

I read about an interrogation technique quite a while back in which the detectives separate all suspects into different rooms and try to get one of them to confess by telling them that the other has already confessed. This technique had a particular name which I can't seem to find anymore (nor can I find any mention of this way of interrogation).

Note: I'm not sure if this is the correct community for this question. I would be happy to be directed to the right place if it is not.

Comment: Hmmmm. Maybe English.SE for a `single-word-request`?  It's not _totally_ off-topic here...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about the law or legal process.

Comment: It depends on what jurisdiction you are referring to. The legal process in the UK, for example, does not allow the police to lie to suspects in interview. The nearest thing I can think of that is used by some in the USA is the Reid Technique (sorry, but I can't add a hyperlink from my phone).

Comment: Regrettably my mod comment on ELU didn't make it back here. — This is not on-topic on ELU because it's asking for the name of a particular technique; this is better suited to a community versed in that specialised area. That would be Law.SE, whose on-topic questions include "Legal terms and language, doctrines and theory; Legal process and procedure". Interrogation is part of the legal process, particularly in jurisdictions like France where there is an examining magistrate.

Comment: This sounds like a simple (incomplete) description of “prisoner’s dilemma”, encouraging each prisoner to betray the other(s).

Comment: The term used in game theory is the "Prisoners' Dilemma." And I vote to reopen because it is part of the legal process.